# How to set temporary System.property for Jetty server in test

Tags: java, junit, jetty, embedded-jetty

I'm using Jetty server to test my app in junit tests. I need to set some properties in tests which my app use. I'm using some standart configuration for Jetty server:

```
Server server = new Server(0);
WebAppContext webAppContext = new WebAppContext();
webAppContext.setResourceBase("some path");
server.setHandler(webAppContext);
```

In my tests I just add required properties to System.property as:

```
System.setProperty("myProperty", "propertyValue");
```

And my app in jetty server use it. But I want don't add these props to System properties. How I can configure jetty server to use these props from another source? I tried to add props as :

```
webAppContext.getInitParams().putAll(Map.of("...","...",....);
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: The answer depends on ... who is using this runtime configuration? (Jetty? your webapp? your 3rd party deps?) and how? (via `System.getProperty()`? or servlet APIs? or other?)